# How do I add a column derived from a select statement within a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

Using SQL Server 2008

**Objective:** Select a series of columns from table1 to insert into table2

**Issue:** In table2 there is one additional column that needs to be inserted that can be derived from a join between table1 and table 3

**Current Code**

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    table1.email,
    table1.phone,
    CASE WHEN table1.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Active,
    CASE WHEN table1.group_id = 3 THEN 5 ELSE table1.group_id END AS RoleId,
    (SELECT
        table3.UserID AS ParentID
     FROM
         table3
     INNER JOIN
         table1 ON
         table3.ID = table1.table3_ID)
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    table1.group_id = 3 AND
    table1.status = 'active'
```

Currently this code does not work and returns "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error.
I am aware this may not be the correct way to use a nested select, what would be the correct way to do this?

Additional data can be provided if necessary.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't join table1 and table3 in your from clause?

Comment: Thank you all answers were good ones, the one I used is the one I checked. I would up vote them all, but I don't have the rep

Comment: Further information on the issue in case anyone is curious...Using the TOP x, I was able to realize there were duplicates entered into the table somehow resulting in the issue. A quick COUNT and GROUP BY showed the duplicated IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want a correlated subquery.  That means that you need to remove `table1` from the subquery:

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.email, table1.phone,
       (CASE WHEN table1.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
       (CASE WHEN table1.group_id = 3 THEN 5 ELSE table1.group_id END) AS RoleId,
       (SELECT table3.UserID 
        FROM table3
        WHERE table3.ID = table1.table3_ID
       ) as ParentID
FROM table1
WHERE table1.group_id = 3 AND table1.status = 'active';
```

If there is more than one possible match in `table3`, then you will need something like `select top 1 table3.UserId` or `select max(table3.UserId)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really (really really really) want to use `subquery` instead of `join` your code is quite well. You should change your subquery's `join` as below.

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    table1.email,
    table1.phone,
    CASE WHEN table1.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Active,
    CASE WHEN table1.group_id = 3 THEN 5 ELSE table1.group_id END AS RoleId,
    (SELECT
        table3.UserID 
     FROM
         table3
     WHERE
         table3.ID = table1.table3_ID) AS ParentID
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    table1.group_id = 3 AND
    table1.status = 'active'
```

Apart from this I put an alias `ParentID` outside the `subquery`.

---

Please consider below code with table aliases. It's good practice to use it because the code is more readable.

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t1.email,
    t1.phone,
    CASE WHEN t1.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Active,
    CASE WHEN t1.group_id = 3 THEN 5 ELSE t1.group_id END AS RoleId,
    (SELECT
        table3.UserID 
     FROM
         table3 t3
     WHERE
         t3.ID = t1.table3_ID) AS ParentID
FROM
    table1 t1
WHERE
    t1.group_id = 3 AND
    t1.status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably solve the more than 1 value error by adding a TOP 1 to the 'select .. from table ' part of the select.  But it may be easier to just inner join them.

```
SELECT
table1.name,
table1.email,
table1.phone,
CASE WHEN table1.status = 'active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Active,
CASE WHEN table1.group_id = 3 THEN 5 ELSE table1.group_id END AS RoleId,
table3.UserID
FROM    table1
INNER JOIN table3 ON
     table3.ID = table1.table3_ID
WHERE
table1.group_id = 3 AND
table1.status = 'active'
```